# mvc display field - text writing outside

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

I'm developing an MVC based web page for a small business.
I've never come across this before...
On my laptop screen and my external monitor, the formatting is fine, however one of the guys in the office has shown me that the text is just writing out of the box in --> direction, so much that it's even adding a horizontal scroll bar!

---------------EDIT---------------------
**ISSUE RESOLVED**

Thanks to @Geeo
Turns out the problem was IE Compatibility mode - set to IE7, changing it to IE9 appears to do the trick.

Comment: it's most likely a css problem so it would be nice if you could provide the css as well or jsfiddle test page

Comment: Can you add the css code for `display-field`, if it is any differend then `display-field-bordered`?

Comment: Is he using Internet Explorer? Which version? Is he using some kind of compatibility mode? (press F12 inside IE and make sure Browser Mode and Document Mode are not set in some old compatibility mode)

Comment: His compatability mode was set to IE7! Silly me, that appears to have worked - thanks a lot guys @Geeo